Build only a section of a Github page
I have a site hosted in Github pages. It contains thousands of pages in a given folder called _clusters. This pages are all built automatically after a push to the repo. There are no issues here, but this process takes quite some (again, there are thousands of these pages)
Sometimes I want to make changes to other sections of the site without disturbing those thousands of already built pages.
The problem is that if I add _clusters  to the exclude section of Jekyll's _config.yml file, make some changes to other sections of the site and then push, Github builds the site removing those thousands of already built pages.
Is there a way to instruct Github to only build a certain portion of the site?

Jekyll does have an experimental incremental build option.
However AFAIK, the build process for GitHub Pages currently doesn't have a cache directory that's persisted across builds. But you can do that with GitHub Actions, or with other hosts (e.g. on Netlify, /opt/build/cache is persisted across builds).
